# Giving implicit variable names to object members for output

Tags: c++, struct, implicit-conversion

Here is a typical implementation of an object of type Struct for console output.

```
void print(List *L, int s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++){
        cout << L[i].member_1 << "\t\t"    // int
             << L[i].member_2 << "\t\t"    // string
             << L[i].member_3 << "\t\t"    // string
             << L[i].member_4 << "\t\t"    // string
             << L[i].member_5 << "\t\t"    // double
             << L[i].member_6 << "\t\t"    // double
             << L[i].member_7 << "\t\t"    // int
             << L[i].member_8 << "\t\t";   // char
    }
}
```

The above seems more lengthy than it could be. So instead, I am trying to code the following.

```
int n = sizeof(L)/sizeof(L[0]);

void print(List *L, int s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << L[i].member_ << j << "\t\t";
        }
    }
}
```

As you can probably guess, I'm raised on JavaScript / post-compiling so it only seems natural to write something like this. I know that I am coding for a compiler so how can I implement the above code? More so than just correcting my code, I would like feed-back or criticism on the logistical approach because my OOP right now is extremely redundant. I am looking for a standard solution / raw C++ code. This is for educational purposes and looking for logic.

Comment: I think `Boost.Variant` can help you doing that.

Comment: `member_n` should be a `std::vector` (or `std::array` if the size is constant).

Comment: @0x499602D2 size is not const. L[n] is a Struct object that acts as a buffer for a .CSV file.

Comment: Do you really name your members with meaningless name `member_1` ?

Comment: @Nawaz, thanks that looks cool. However, I am looking for a standard solution / raw C++ code. This is for educational purposes and looking for logic.

Comment: @Jarod42 I said I'm a JS guy didn't I? Joking, no I don't, the struct is an abstract of financial records.

Comment: For classification, my actual buffers have typical variables but they are going to use level 3 child nodes or a parallel array. Can anybody relate to this scenario??

Comment: Can you change the structure to something like std::tuple? You could then use some variadic-template recursion on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in reflection mechanism in C++. Static reflection could be a topic for upcoming versions of the language, but right now, there is no general way to somehow enumerate all members of a class. So you have to list all your members explicitly somewhere. But this can be done reusable at a single place, here is an example:

```
template <typename F>
void for_each_member(List& l, F f)
{
    f(l.member_1);
    f(l.member_2);
    f(l.member_3);
    f(l.member_4);
    f(l.member_5);
    f(l.member_6);
    f(l.member_7);
    f(l.member_8);
}
```

This template function invokes a functor for every member of the given `List`. With this tool, your `print` function could look like this:

```
struct print_member
{
    template <typename T>
    void operator()(const T& m)
    {
        cout << m << "\t\t";
    }
};

void print(List *L, int s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        for_each_member(L[i], print_member());
    }
}
```

With C++14, we could even do without the `print_member` functor and instead use a generic lambda taking an `auto` parameter:

```
void print(List *L, int s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        for_each_member(L[i], [](const auto& m)
        {
            cout << m << "\t\t";
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, close enough for now; this looks great. That's awesome how you are casting L[x] to auto as a reference. Thanks for the epic aha.